# NASM X86_64 global variable from C

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I am completely new to NASM assembly on X86_64.I would like to access my variable toto in an asm programm and increment its value. So far I'm doing the following:

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t toto;
extern void modifytoto(void);

int main() {
    toto=0;
    modifytoto();
    printf("toto = %d \n",toto);
    return 0;
}
```

and the assembly program is the following (the incrementation is pseudo-code).

```
global  modifytoto
global  toto

section .text
        modifytoto:
            mov rax, 1
            mov toto, rax
            ret
```

I can't use toto as an argument to modifytoto() because this is supposed to be used in a more complex program in which I don't wan't to modify the arguments.

I'm assemblying with the following cmd

```
nasm -f elf64 -o mix_asm.o kernel3.asm
```

and I'm getting this message:

```
kernel3.asm:7: error: symbol `toto' undefined
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Why do you think that 'mov toto, rax' increments toto's value? mov overwrites the toto value and its value becomes 1, but not one more. Try add toto, 1

Comment: Cool, the asm instructions were just here to indicate my purpose, but you're right. Thanks !

Comment: Why is add toto, 1 giving me this message ?
invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: @syf write `add DWORD PTR toto, 1` and then read the manual before coming back for further questions.

Comment: Cool thanks ! In the end, I wrote             

    mov rax, 1
    add [toto], rax

And that was ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the line

```
extern toto
```

somewhere before you use `toto` to tell NASM that `toto` is an external symbol. That's like in C: The compiler has no idea what `toto` is supposed to be if you don't tell it by declaring `toto`.